# Tabbed Navigation Using a List

Tags: html, css, tabs

What is the best way to adjust the li elements to fill the entire width of the div the tab bar will be located in?

Comment: Can you provide some more info on what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

i'd prefer not to have to use `width:33%`, but this works.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.menuTop {width:400px;border:1px solid red;}
        div.menuTop li  {float:left; width:33%; border:1px solid green;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menuTop">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Put 4 <li> in your <ul>, use 25% ;) and using display:inline-box prevents you from using the extra <div> to clear the float.

Comment: You're aware that using `<li>` elements outside of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` is invalid?

Comment: why not post a better solution?